# EXCEPT SQL statement in SQL Server not returning expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables which are identical but reside on different servers. One table is missing a row which I have verified. I am trying to compare these tables for finding the missing records

by

```
SELECT  GUID FROM dbo.tableA
EXCEPT 
SELECT  GUID FROM [Server2].MyDatabase.dbo.tableA
```

or the other way around

```
SELECT GUID FROM [Server2].MyDatabase.dbo.tableA
EXCEPT 
SELECT GUID FROM dbo.tableA
```

Both queries return zero results. I have used `select count(*)` on both tables and the count is different

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any feedback in advance

Answer (score 6):

The count can be different and it is still possible for `except` to return zero rows.  How?  If there are duplicates in one or both tables.

Here is a modification that can help you find the differences:

```
SELECT GUID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GUID ORDER BY GUID) as seqnum
FROM dbo.tableA
EXCEPT 
SELECT GUID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GUID ORDER BY GUID) as seqnum
FROM [Server2].MyDatabase.dbo.tableA
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the `EXCEPT` operator does not function as expected when working with linked servers. Why? I don't know.

As a workaround I insert the rows from the remote server into a local temp table and then compare: (I also copy the local one to a second temp table for other reasons)

```
Select GUID
  Into #Server2_tblA
  From [Server2].MyDatabase.dbo.tableA;

Select GUID
  Into #Local_tblA
  From dbo.tableA;

Select GUID From #Server2_tblA
Except
Select GUID From #Local_tblA;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Table A values does not presented in MyDatabase.dbo.tableA.Using Not exist caluse for get this result

```
SELECT GUID 
FROM dbo.tableA WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                                 FROM [Server2].MyDatabase.dbo.tableA 
                                 WHERE GUID = [Server2].MyDatabase.dbo.tableA.GUID )
```

Comment: While this may be a valid answer, you are much more likely to help others by explaining what the code does and how it works. Code-only answers tend to receive less positive attention and aren't as useful as other answers.